GCP Regional Standard Disk Capacity
A regional standard disk of size 10GB was created from a snapshot of a disk. The size of the snapshot is 0 and the source disk size is 10GB. Unfortunately, I don't have any information regarding the type of the source disk. However, GCP documentation says that the minimum capacity for a regional standard disk is 200GB. How come a 10GB disk was created? I tried all the possible ways to create a 10GB regional standard disk but failed each time. Are there any special exceptions to creating a 10GB regional standard disk? If so, what are they?

How have you determined 10 GB? The size of the formatted volume or the actual allocated size of the persistent disk?

Its the actual allocated size of the persistent disk

Add a picture showing the persistent disk configuration from the Google Cloud Console GUI.

Can you verify through the console if the disk type is indeed 10 GB? You may do so by going to:

Head to your Console

Select Compute Engine

Head to Disks

Send a screenshot of your Disks, specifically the Type and Size.


Just FYI, there are four general disk types - balanced, ssd, standard, and extreme. A regional standard disk minimum size is 200 GB. Not all regional PDs are regional standard PDs.
You may view the comparison here.
I tried replicating it through the Console and gcloud using the command:
gcloud beta compute disks create <disk ID> --project=<project ID> --type=pd-standard --size=10GB --region=us-central1 --replica-zones=projects/<project ID>/zones/us-central1-a,projects/<project ID>/zones/us-central1-f
and both methods are failing, as expected.

Edit: I have checked some cases internally, and indeed, it is possible to create standard disks under 200 GB. Basically, due to legacy issues, you can still create smaller disks in some specific ways, and it has been kept that way so as not to break some customers.
If you run the command gcloud compute disks create testdisk --size=1GB --zone=us-central1-c you will successfully create a pd-standard disk with 1 GB size (10 GB is the minimum size for Zonal).
I still can't find a way to create a regional standard PD and will update this comment if I do.
